# Converting from an integer to its binary representation

Tags: binary, go, numeric

Has anyone got an idea if there is any inbuilt functionality in Go for converting from any one of the numeric types to its binary number form.

For example, if `123` was the input, the string `"1111011"` would be the output.

Comment: This is done automatically. Decimal numbers are converted and used in binary form.

Comment: Numbers in a programming language already are stored in binary form. Maybe you meant outputting them in base 2? Or 32-bit two's complement base 2? Of course neither will make sense for floating point numbers, where you want the textual representation of the IEEE whatever format. Or just outputting the raw bit patterns to a stream?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The `strconv` package has `FormatInt`, which accepts an `int64` and lets you specify the base.

```
n := int64(123)

fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(n, 2)) // 1111011
```

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/leGVAELMhv

> http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt
>
> `func FormatInt(i int64, base int) string`
>
> FormatInt returns the string representation of i in the given base, for 2 <= base <= 36. The result uses the lower-case letters 'a' to 'z' for digit values >= 10.

Comment: thanks alot for that...I need to read the manuals more carefully.

Comment: How to format negative int(signed int), `fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(n, 2))` is `-11`, but I want two's compliment format.

Comment: What is the reverse of this? If I need the integer from a binary string?

Comment: @majidarif, use
    `i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1101", 2, 64)`

Comment: I was having trouble parsing `"11111111"` to `uint8` using `strconv.ParseInt("11111111", 2, 8)` and just discovered method `strconv.ParseUint` that works as expected :)

Answer (score 85):

See also the [fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package:

```
n := int64(123)
fmt.Printf("%b", n)  // 1111011
```

Comment: As @Luke Antins shows, the length of the binary output can be specified by adding a number between the percent and the b. E.g. '%08b' leads to 00000001.

Comment: `s := fmt.Sprintf("%b", 123)`

Answer (score 16):

```
package main

import . "fmt"

func main(){
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",0,0)
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",1,1)
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",2,2)
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",3,3)
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",4,4)
    Printf("%d == %08b\n",5,5)
}
```

results in:

```
0 == 00000000
1 == 00000001
2 == 00000010
3 == 00000011
4 == 00000100
5 == 00000101
```

Answer (score 11):

This code works on big integers `*big.Int` :

```
x := big.NewInt(123)
s := fmt.Sprintf("%b", x)
// s == "1111011"
```

because `*big.Int` implements the [`fmt.Formatter`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Formatter) interface.

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23317788/871134

Answer (score 4):

An alternate way for the accepted answer would be to simply do

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%b", 123)
fmt.Println(s)                 // 1111011
```

For a more rich representation you can use the `unsafe` package(strongly discouraged) as

```
a := int64(123)
byteSliceRev := *(*[8]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
byteSlice := make([]byte, 8)
for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
    byteSlice[i] = byteSliceRev[7 - i]
}
fmt.Printf("%b\n", byteSlice)
```

This works for negative integers too.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer provided by @Mark

Although the OP asked how to print an integer, I often want to look at more then 64 bits worth of data, without my eyes boggling:

```
/* --- Credit to Dave C in the comments --- */
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("<%s>\n", fmtBits([]byte{0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xF0, 0x0D, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xF0, 0x0D}))

    // OUTPUT:
    // <11011110 10101101 10111110 11101111 11110000 00001101 11011110 10101101 10111110 11101111 11110000 00001101>
}

func fmtBits(data []byte) []byte {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for _, b := range data {
        fmt.Fprintf(&buf, "%08b ", b)
    }
    buf.Truncate(buf.Len() - 1) // To remove extra space
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

[see this code in play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/ifobZWv_du)

Comment: If you're going to hard-code to stdout then just output in the loop; if it's a formatting function then have it return `[]byte`. Repeatedly appending to a `string` like that is inefficient, better is to use something like a `bytes.Buffer` (or if only it did leading zeros, using just `strconv.AppendInt` with a plain `[]byte`). Calling `strings.TrimSpace` on each iteration just to handle the single extra space is very inefficient. E.g. something like https://play.golang.org/p/ifobZWv_du on a 1kB input is ~50x faster and uses ~1/50th of the memory.

Comment: Efficiency never crossed my mind, but on all counts you are correct and your solution is much better then mine, thanks! Display more then 64-bits worth of data was my goal :)

Answer (score 3):

Unsafe pointers must be used to correctly represent negative numbers in binary format.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unsafe"
)

func bInt(n int64) string {
    return strconv.FormatUint(*(*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(&n)), 2)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bInt(-1))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/GxXjjWMyC4x

Comment: This should be the answer if we want to convert **negative** decimal into *bitwise* representation using two's complement(without `-` sign), not into mathematical binary representation(using - sign).

Answer (score 1):

Many above answers do **not** work if you use **negative** decimals.

Here is the *simplest* answer. Also works with negative decimals.

```
var a int64 = -1
fmt.Printf("%b\n", uint64(a)) // 11111.... (not -1)
```

([Go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/wjF_P3E9Mri))

You can also use `fmt.Sprintf` instead of `fmt.Printf` if you want a `string` variable.

This way, you can convert negative decimal into bitwise representation using *two's complement* (without `-` sign), not into mathematical binary representation (using `-` sign). (As I commented in Soslan's answer.)

(Soslan and Vaibhav's answers also work with negative numbers, using the `unsafe` package.)

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    var x = time.Now().UnixNano()
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, x)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", buf.Bytes())
}
```

- example: https://go.dev/play/p/vZHSUsRr33v
- test: https://go.dev/play/p/us-stq22KMG