# Golang Big Integers to Binary String

Tags: go, biginteger

I see it's simple to convert golang's big int (math/big package) to a string, but is there any straightforward way of converting a big int to a binary string?

Comment: What is a binary string?

Comment: @Anonymous A string of the form 10110101011010010101010 I guess.

Answer (score 13):

Should be as easy as this:

```
i := big.NewInt(2014)
s := fmt.Sprintf("%b", i) // 11111011110

fmt.Println(s)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The reason why this works is that [`big.Int` implements](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Format) the [`Formatter` interface](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Formatter).

Comment: Actually, `*big.Int` (pointer type) implements the `Formatter` interface :)